# How to create custom annotation that will add new property source

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I have several spring boot applications in which I want to place a custom annotation (in some bean). The annotation will have one field (e.g. propertyValue). That value I want to add to the Environment as a part of a new PropertySource.

My idea is to create a bean that will inject Environment and then add a new PropertySource to it. The missing piece is how to connect custom annotation with this bean.

Any ideas?

Comment: Basically you want Spring to know about the custom Annotation right?

Comment: Yes and to execute bean method with a value passed in the annotation.

Comment: Why standard annotation is not good for you?

Comment: I don't want to read the property source from a file.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use different property file for different environment. Spring Boot handles this already without need for custom beans or annotations.

Just use [Profile-Specific Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) Spring Boot feature. You can define profile via system property (e.g. `-Dspring.profiles.active=PROD-US-EAST-REGION`)